# Efficient small joint manipulation?

Tags: self-defense, streetfight

(I understand that this scenario is unrealistic. This discussion is based purely on theory.)

Let's say, if such an opportunity presents itself in an unregulated fight, what is the most effective and fail-safe method to break someone's fingers (through small joint manipulation, of course)?

From which angle should one bend the fingers? And is it necessary to fix the position of the hand? Is it possible to execute with only one hand available?

Comment: Do you need to literally *break bone*? Because it is quite probable that you will destroy the ligaments (ie. they joints) instead of the compact, short bone of the phalanges (ie. finger bones).

Comment: @Philip No, tearing the ligaments would be fine :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biomechanically easiest way is to grab a single finger with your whole hand from the palm of the targeted hand. From there, it only needs a "hammer swing" motion with all of your body: upwards if the finger grabbed is pointing down, downwards if the finger grabbed is pointing up, ie. you bend them onto the back of the hand. The latter movement (finger pointing up, you pressing down) is biomechanically slightly easier as it goes with the gravity.

Basically, it is not as fine or technical as "small-joint manipulation" might suggest. You just grab one, two, or even three fingers and jerk them violently towards the side (works for single fingers, esp. pinkie) or, much better, back of the hand it hangs at. You will pop the joints (most of the times the metacarpophalangeal joint) pretty easily. You do not even have to fixate the wrist or hand as the basic tension in the wrist will suffice as counter-force to have the joint pop simply because of leverage. As long as they do not *actively relax* their wrist and arms, it works. Even if they do, it will still be too fast most of the times. The thumb is harder to come by due to other strength-leverage ratio but is a valid target as well.

This is also the main reason why many self-defense teachers are so adamant on pointing out that you block/parry with closed fists: It is pretty easy to break fingers if you can single one out in a straight or almost-straight position. Therefore, *every* move towards the opponent, no matter whether it is block/parry, punch, or grab should involve keeping your fingers together and thumb close and ideally close the hand to a fist while approaching or on contact.

That being said, it is not an easy feat to grab a finger, like at all. The easiest way is literally having them grab you first: you can fixate the hand - not to make the finger manipulation work but to get hold of the finger in the first place - and go on from there. Thus, my highest bet would be on: let them grab you, fixate the hand and work into some form of arm-bar (turning towards the side of the opponent and their body away to get out of range of the other hand) and pull one finger out. Not really high-percentage in any case. Fingers that don't grab are the fastest part you have tondeal with, after all...

Now, as there is theory out of the way, I would like to add that I myself have pretty strong hands and like to use them in various ways so that while I do never *spread* my fingers when I am teaching or being in a position where I have to use self-defense, I certainly am not dogmatic about having a closed fist since my hand is always *under full tension* at the moment of (or, depending on technique, slightly after) contact.

I will also have to add a disclaimer: While a broken finger *does* hurt, it may well be that in an all-out fight with an enraged, maybe intoxicated person, all you achieve is making someone **really, really angry** and - equally if not more important - does add a **ton of adrenaline** to their system within seconds, which makes them faster, stronger, and more pain-resistant. A broken finger does not diminish the fighting ability of a person as much as one might think. And there is a good chance that it makes the whole encounter *harder, nor easier* to survive unscathed.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks for high percentage techniques against the finger joints. By "high percentage", I mean higher chance of getting it to work successfully and effectively.

The first thing to realize is that hands are low percentage targets in the free fighting range. By "free fighting", I mean both people are free to move around, and nobody is holding onto the other.

In the free fighting range, your focus will be on punching, kicking, blocking, evasion, strategy, timing, etc. You shouldn't be thinking about grabbing a hand out of thin air. Your opponent's hand is flailing around quickly, and if you go to reach for it, he's just going to pull it out of the way and then knock you out because you're too busy thinking about that hand that you're not defending against his other hand or his feet.

So the free fighting range won't work. What will?

The answer is that you have to be in the clinch or ground fighting range. One or both of you are holding onto each other. At this point, you can find your way to his fingers, prying one of them apart from his clenched fist, and snap it.

Now, how you do that while defending yourself is the subject for grappling arts. Usually they say don't try to do it, because there are more reliable techniques to use, instead.

In my opinion, there's almost always a better thing to do besides focusing on fingers to attack. Even if you happen to find yourself able to attack a finger, chances are there are more effective ways to end the fight from that position.

And so I mostly see finger attacks as a last resort kind of a thing in order to break an "unbreakable" hold.

They can also be used very effectively by someone who is a high level grappler. Someone who does the work of incorporating finger attacks in their grappling is able to use them more effectively than someone who's just doing them as a last resort. The same is true for wrist locks, which you only see BJJ people doing around black belt level.

So let's talk about attacks on fingers as a last resort...

Sometimes when someone has an unbreakable hold of someone else, the only way out of the hold is to make it really painful for your opponent to continue holding. So you pry open one finger and snap it. The guy probably will release the hold before that happens. Biting and pinching is another thing people do. Eye gouging. Fish hooking. Using elbow strikes or headbutts. Etc. These are last resort methods of getting out of holds. Some are more effective than others.

How easy is it to just pry a finger open from a clenched fist? It depends on the hold. If he's holding onto your clothing, you can sometimes just pull your clothing up and away from his pinky joint to get it to open a little. And then you feel it with your other hand and get right in there to pry open that pinky as soon as you can.

That's another thing. Which fingers should you target and how many? The answer is usually the weakest finger, the pinky. But really it's whichever finger is going to be easiest to pry open at the time, the one that's most available to you. And you just need one finger. More than one finger will just make it more difficult for you.

Some kung-fu stylists, for example, have a bad habit of leaving their index finger pointing out even when they're holding onto your wrist or your lapel. They're often told that they need to do that in order to allow the chi to flow through the hand, making it stronger for chin-na technique. Maybe there is an application where that makes sense, but it also makes that finger very vulnerable. Grab that sucker and twist!

Another thing you can do instead of prying open a finger is to squeeze down on the finger while pressing his joint in on itself. It's hard to describe. Bujinkan does it a lot. Here's a video showing it against the thumb, which is probably the most common target of this technique:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ccdZYaAPgM

Another thing you can try in cases where you're trying to get that hand to release enough for you to grab a finger is to slam the hand against a hard object or use your knuckle and jamb it right into a pressure point on his hand. The pain or shock just might be enough for him to react long enough for you to get one of his fingers loose. Again, this is going to take time, and usually it's just a last resort kind of thing. There are usually better things to do than concentrating on prying open the hand.

As for advanced grapplers utilizing attacks on fingers, I have seen this before often in classical jujitsu. Wally Jay's "small circle jujitsu" tutorials are probably a must see if you really want to learn this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jM0pTpK7SeQ

There are a lot of "sneaky" ways of attacking the fingers, which you'll learn over time if you want to make it part of your training. And advanced grapplers, BJJ people, etc. can learn to incorporate them in their regular ground game.

That being said, finger locking / small joint manipulation is not allowed in competition BJJ and submission grappling in most tournament venues. You can, however, use these if your school allows them. And usually it will only be the more advanced students who are allowed to use them, because it's too easy for beginners to torque those fingers and do real damage to an opponent.

Now notice the contradiction I seemingly just made. I said finger attacks were low percentage techniques and should only be done as a last resort. But then I said that these shouldn't be used by beginners in BJJ class, because the chances of doing real damage is too great. Both of these statements are true. How?

The reason why is because BJJ class is not the same as a fight. Your partner in class may not be trying to hold on as strong as he can. He's not going to be going full force. He's going to be thinking about the techniques he just learned, trying to find ways of using them. He's going to be loose and won't be thinking about defending against finger attacks. Furthermore, you have plenty of time to find a situation where he gives you his fingers. So when you're rolling against him, you probably will find that opportunity. This is not like a self-defense situation in real life where things are much more intense, happen very quickly, and have severe consequences for choosing the wrong technique.

And by the way, if you do crank on your partner's fingers in BJJ class, good luck coming back to the school again. Haha.

That's all I really wanted to say about this. In conclusion, most people should think of these as last resort kinds of techniques that aren't things you should try normally. But for advanced grapplers, adding finger attacks to their game would make sense because they understand when it's possible to use them effectively.

Hope that helps.